# How to query a table that has ENUM column and keep the ENUM type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM.

I have a table in SQL DB with an `id` column, and a column called `b`, which is type enum, and can take values `('example_1', 'example_2')`.

In Python, I have an `Enum` class like this:

```
class BTypes(enum.Enum):
    EXAMPLE_1 = 'example_1'
    EXAMPLE_2 = 'example_2'
```

For querying the table, I have an ORM like this:

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = "example"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b = Column(Enum(BTypes).values_callable)
```

When I do `session.query(Example).all()`, the objects that I get back have `str` type for the `b` attribute. In other words:

```
data = session.query(Example).all()
print(data[0].b)
# Outputs
# example_1
```

I want that the `Example` object for the attribute `b` has an `enum` type, not `str`. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base.metadata.create_all(create_engine("sqlite://"))` with:

> ```py
> b = Column(Enum(BTypes).values_callable)
> ```

gives me:

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'example', column 'b'): Can't generate DDL for NullType(); did you forget to specify a type on this Column?

## About `NullType`

Since `Enum(BTypes).values_callable` is `None`, SQLAlchemy defaults to `NullType`.

From https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.NullType:

> The `NullType` can be used within SQL expression invocation without issue, it just has no behavior either at the expression construction level or at the bind-parameter/result processing level.

In other words, when we `query`, its value is simply assigned as-is from the database.

## How to use the `Enum.values_callable` parameter

From https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum:

> In order to persist the values and not the names, the `Enum.values_callable` parameter may be used. The value of this parameter is a user-supplied callable, which is intended to be used with a PEP-435-compliant enumerated class and returns a list of string values to be persisted. For a simple enumeration that uses string values, a callable such as `lambda x: [e.value for e in x]` is sufficient.

That would be:

```py
b = Column(Enum(BTypes, values_callable=lambda x: [e.value for e in x]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code to query table as below to get as Enum:

```
   class Example(Base):
        __tablename__ = "example"
         id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
         b = Column(Enum(BTypes))
```

**Note** that *values_callable* typically return list of string values.
Do have a look into the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html?highlight=enum#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) for more information

> values_callable –
> A callable which will be passed the PEP-435 compliant enumerated type, which should then return a list of string values to be persisted. This allows for alternate usages such as using the string value of an enum to be persisted to the database instead of its name.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer doesn't work. Removing values callable gives an error. Reason is, without values callable, sqlaclehmy thinks the string values are `'EXAMPLE_1'` and `'EXAMPLE_2'`, and the sql table does not have these values.